# Eigen vectors for an orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ and the identity I, show that the matrices (I+M) AND $(I-M)^{-1}$ commute.

For a real skew- symmetric matrix A, the matrix N is defined by

$N=(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}$

(a)Prove that N is orthogonal.
(b)
(i)Show that the eigenvectors of A are also eigenvectors of N.
Part (a) is already done.
Answering (b)(i)
$N\mathbf{X}=\lambda \mathbf{X}$

$[(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}]\mathbf{X}=\lambda \mathbf{X}$

$[(I-A)^{-1}+A(I-A)^{-1}]\mathbf{X}-\lambda \mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$

$[(I-A)^{-1}+A(I-A)^{-1}-\lambda ]\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$

$[(I-A)^{-1}+A(I-A)^{-1}-\lambda ]\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$

$[(I-A)^{-1}+AA^{-1}+(I-A)^{-1}A-\lambda ]\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$

$[(I-A)^{-1}+(I-A)^{-1}A-\lambda ]\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$

$[(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)\mathbf{X}=\lambda\mathbf{X}$

Through my attempts, I get to prove commutativity, I need to prove for eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $(\lambda,x)$ is an eigenpair of $A$, then $(I-A)x=(1-\lambda)x$. Therefore, as long as $\lambda\ne1$, we have $\frac1{1-\lambda}x=(I-A)^{-1}x$ and in turn $x$ is also an eigenvector of $(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}$. So, the key here is to prove that $\lambda\ne1$ (or equivalently, to prove that $(I-A)^{-1}$ or $N$ exist). This actually has nothing to do with the other two parts of the question. All you need is that $A$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: It still sounds unclear, but I can see some light in it. Is it possible to give some more details on it, I am new to this. @user1551

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{X}=(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)\mathbf{X}$

$=(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)\mathbf{X}$

$=(I-A)^{-1}(1+\lambda)\mathbf{X}$

$=(1+\lambda)(I-A)^{-1}\mathbf{X}$

$N\mathbf{X}=\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}\mathbf{X}$

Hence same $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{N}$ have similar eigenvectors but different eigenvalues