# Eigenvalues of a real orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that the eigenvectors of a real orthogonal matrix are also eigenvectors of $\mathbf{N}$ are (i) $e^{+i\alpha}$ (ii) $e^{-i\alpha}$ (iii) $+1$ or $-1$ ,where $\alpha$ is real.
Hence show that, when $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{N}$, (given $\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is real skew symmetric),
$\operatorname{det}\mathbf{n}=1$, and that there exists a direction $\mathbf{X}$ in which $\mathbf{AX}=0$.

According to me, we have got to work with determinant here, but I can barely see where to start.

For a start, I thought

$A\mathbf{X}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$

$A^{T}\mathbf{X}=A^{-1}\mathbf{X}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$ (since orthogonal)

$A^{-1}\mathbf{X}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$

Working out determinant

$\operatorname{det}(A^{-1}-\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{I})=0$

Then it is a blackout.

I have posted an answer for (iii), I need help for (i) and (ii). Its where the use of complex conjugation comes in play. Please help.

Comment: Mostly a duplicate of your earlier question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665156/eigen-vectors-for-an-orthogonal-matrix), I think. Though the new question is very difficult to understand, so it's hard to say what it's asking.

Comment: @bubba,you are right, it is the second part of this former question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665156/eigen-vectors-for-an-orthogonal-matrix).

Comment: It is classical material about "Cayley transform". Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A\mathbf{X}=\lambda\mathbf{X}$(1)

We take (1) and its conjugate transpose

$(A\mathbf{X})^{T}=(\lambda\mathbf{X})^T=\lambda\mathbf{X}^T$(2)

Multiply (2)and (1)

$(A\mathbf{X})^{T}A\mathbf{X}=\lambda\mathbf{X}^T\lambda\mathbf{X}$

$\mathbf{X}^TA^TA\mathbf{X}=\lambda^2\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$

Since A is orthogonal, A^{T}=A^{-1}

$\mathbf{X}^TA^{-1}A\mathbf{X}=\lambda^2\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$

$\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}=\lambda^2\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$

Dividing by $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$

$\lambda^2=1$, $\lambda=±1$,